# No such host is known

Tags: sql-server

Estoy tratando de poner en produccion una tienda virtual y al querer ejecutarla en el host donde la hospedo me presenta el error de conexion a SQL, el detalle es que en desarrollo si conecta sin problema y es un servidor externo el de SQL por lo que si esta aceptando conexiones remotas. El error es el siguiente:
[image: Error al ejecutar]

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda

Comment: No hay mucho que se pueda hacer. Esta mal la conexion al servidor. Tenes acceso desde ahi?

Comment: O el nombre del `hots` está mal escrito, @gbianchi.

Comment: buen dia, tengo otro aplicativo que se conecta a la misma base de datos sin problema, el punto esta en que el que presenta el error esta alojado en el host del dominio y el que no esta a traves de un dns que es llamado, pueden ver ambos trabajando en www.ideaconfort.com la opcion tienda es el que funciona sin problema y que es externo y la opcion tienda safe es el que esta en el dominio y presenta el problema, repito ambos van a la misma DB. Por eso se que si esta aceptando conexion remota y esta funcionando.

Comment: Sospecho que en el servidor no puede resolverse el nombre del servidor de base de datos. Digamos que tu cadena de conexión apunta a `dbserver.xyz.com`, y por alguna razón, el equipo servidor no logra resolver este nombre. Puedes intentar hacer un ´dnslookup dbserver.xyz.com´ en el servidor. ¿funciona?. Si no funciona, habla con el administrador de red, y cuando eso funcione, tu aplicación se conectará.